# Оператор && для метки

Tags: c++, c, gcc, операторы, goto

Увидел необычную конструкцию в коде:

```
int main() {
L: goto *(&&L);
}
```

Что означает выражение `*(&&L)` для некоторой метки `L`?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/c-double-address-operator]

Comment: @JohnDoe там к типу он применяется, а не к метке

Comment: @Ivan43 - про применение его к метке - написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777990/is-it-possible-to-store-the-address-of-a-label-in-a-variable-and-use-goto-to-jum Уже перевожу...

Comment: Бесконечный цикл через переход по адресу метки. (кто-то демонстрирует свои познания в расширениях GCC (или просто шутит))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Круть какая!

Не могу не перевести ответ с английского стековерфлоу, потому что сам удивился, что не знал такой штуки:

1. C++ Double Address Operator применительно к типу. [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/).

`&&` - новшество, появившееся в C++11. `int&&` a означает, что "a" является r-value ссылкой на значение r. `&&` обычно используется только для объявления параметра функции. И для этого требуется только r-value значения.

Если Вы не знаете, что такое r-значение, простое объяснение состоит в том, что у него нет адреса памяти. Например. число `6` и символ `'v'` являются r-value значениями. В выражении `int a`, a является l-value значением, однако `(a+2)` является r-value значением. Например:

```
    void foo(int&& a)
    {
        //Some magical code...
    }

    int main()
    {
        int b;
        foo(b); //Error. An rValue reference cannot be pointed to a lValue.
        foo(5); //Compiles with no error.
        foo(b+3); //Compiles with no error.

        int&& c = b; //Error. An rValue reference cannot be pointed to a lValue.
        int&& d = 5; //Compiles with no error.
    }
```

2. C++ Double Address Operator применительно к метке в коде. [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777990/).

Рассмотрим такой пример, где мы пытаемся получить адрес метки:

```
int main (void)
{
  int i=1;
  void* the_label_pointer;

  the_label:

  the_label_pointer = &the_label;

  if( i-- )
    goto *the_label_pointer;

  return 0;
}
```

Стандарты `C` и `C++` не поддерживают эту функцию. Однако `GCC` ( `GNU GCC`, для педантов) включает нестандартное расширение для этого, как описано в [этой статье](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). По сути, они добавили специальный оператор `«&&»`, который сообщает адрес метки как тип `«void*»`.